# What can I do about piracy?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

Help! My games are being pirated! People are choosing to get copies of my material illegally rather than giving me large sums of money instead! I seem to be given the option to "Warn Them" or "Sue Them":

[image]

What are the repercussions of each of these actions? Will they affect the number of fans I have or my company's reputation? Will this actually increase the number of games sold? What can I do about piracy?

Comment: If the message warning you about piracy looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfg0K.png), then perhaps you should [consider buying the game rather than downloading it illegally](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfg0K.png)!

Comment: I think this question ([and this current answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115541/4797)) is off-topic in Arqade. From [the FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq): "Please note, however, that site policies prohibit questions of the following types: ... *Piracy, and support with pirated games*."

Comment: I think you're lacking knowledge of the game in hand, or else you wouldn't have created such a silly comment...

Comment: @galacticninja This is *not* a screen from the [pirated](http://www.greenheartgames.com/2013/04/29/what-happens-when-pirates-play-a-game-development-simulator-and-then-go-bankrupt-because-of-piracy/) version of this game. Piracy is a game mechanic in the legit game too.

Comment: http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/123585-Pirating-Game-Dev-Tycoon-Dooms-Players-to-be-Ruined-By-Piracy for details of the cracked version.  This message looks different though and may be a genuine mechanic.

Comment: @fredley and kalina: I see. (I thought kalina was talking about the pirated version since the question was immediately self-answered). [This answer by kalina](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115542/4797) still talks about the actual pirated version of the game, though (from reading the article you and Christi linked to). It mentions: "*perhaps you should consider buying the game rather than downloading it illegally!*" I thought support regarding pirated games are not allowed here. If it's a legit in-game mechanic, only that should be discussed and not the mechanics of the pirated game.

Comment: It's ok - everybody makes mistakes every now and again!

Comment: @kalina I forgive you. =) (I also just realized that the answer was deleted and was inserted as a comment above, making me look like a complete idiot. Thanks mods!)

Comment: @fredley and others who missed the now-deleted self-answer: I'm *not* just talking about the question, but [this self-answer (now deleted; needs to have 10K+ rep to view)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115541/what-can-i-do-about-piracy/115542#115542). ([Also, this.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9191327#9191327))

Comment: Huh, actually I'd fire this guy for wasting work time on identifying pirates _before_ asking for my permission...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you're prompted to deal with your pirates, you're given two options - warn them or sue them.

If you choose to **warn** your pirates, your fans will respond positively to the fact you didn't launch all out war against gamers pirating your game. You'll be presented with a brief bit of story about how piracy is rife within the games industry and that many developers are taking gamers to court over it, while others are taking a more relaxed approach to the issue. You will get some positive feedback from them and also gain some additional fans.

If you choose to **sue** your pirates, you'll get a backlash from your fans, who will be unhappy about you being heavy handed over the situation. You will lose a *lot* of fans as a result of your actions, but gain some money back in legal claims;

[image]

If you are not given two options like in the screenshot on the question, but instead receive a screenshot like below, then you're actually a real life pirate who stole the game instead of buying it;

[image: real pirates]

Perhaps you should [consider buying the game rather than downloading it illegally](http://www.greenheartgames.com/2013/04/29/what-happens-when-pirates-play-a-game-development-simulator-and-then-go-bankrupt-because-of-piracy/)!

Comment: If you've lost **minus** 1,666 fans does it mean you've gained that many? :/

Comment: No, it's not a double negative - I actually lost a lot more fans than the number presented on the message as well, since I had ~8k fans before the message, and a month after the message I had ~2k fans