# Should I let fans of my game continue developing a fan game or not?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I recently got this message from my employee:

[image: A bunch of fans are creating a fan game. Stop them or let them be?]
<sup>*"Boss, I've discovered that some really dedicated fans of pirate adventure have created a fan game using a lot of the material from our game. They don't make any money with it and just seem to do it for fellow fans. Our legal advisors strongly suggest that we shouldn't allow this to go on. What do you want to do?"*</sup>

A bunch of fans have re-used material from my game about a pirate's adventure in [The Scene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warez_scene). Should I follow my lawyers or should I stop them from doing this?

**What are the advantages and disadvantages of stopping the fans or letting them be?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you basically have two choices - stop them or let them be. This mechanic isn't that deep and from my experience so far you'll only come across this message once during the game regardless of which option you choose.

If you let your fans continue with their development, then they'll love you for it, you'll get a thank you notice and gain more fans.

If you stop them, then your fans will not be happy and you will lose fans.

The outcomes are pretty much the same as the options to [deal with piracy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115541/27134) but you won't get money out of it either way.

Comment: Does this mean that choosing 'Stop them' has no advantage at all? Also, know details about how many fans I'm gonna lose or get?

Comment: Nope - you won't get money out of it (or at least I haven't in the playthroughs where I stopped them). As for how many fans you lose, it's a percentage of the number of fans you have. Not sure on the percentage though as it seems to vary.

Comment: That's a pretty bad game then (game dev tycoon). There should be reactions to your decisions... like they get more popular than your game and start to drain money away.